# Add data.frame objects' names from a list in columns in said data.frame objects list

Tags: r, list, object, automation, names

I want to know how to add data.frame objects' names from a list in columns in said data.frame objects list.

I created a list of `lm()` objects where only the DVs (known as `DV_col`) vary (either `mpg`, `drat`, `disp`). The general format of the lm() is: `lm( DV_col ~ cyl, data = mtcars)`.

```
# sets up data

## list of DVs to use
mtcars_DVs <- data.frame(c("mpg", "drat", "disp"))
names(mtcars_DVs)[names(mtcars_DVs) == "c..mpg....drat....disp.."] <- "Variable_name"
mtcars_DVs$Variable_name <- as.character(mtcars_DVs$Variable_name)

## creates lm object list
# ---- NOTE: creates object list
lm_list <-
  lapply(mtcars_DVs$Variable_name,
         function(DV_list) wrapr::let(
           c(DV_col = DV_list, 
             dataset_obj = "mtcars", 
             IV_col_key = "cyl"), 
           (lm(
             DV_col ~ 
               IV_col_key, 
             data = dataset_obj
           )
           )
         )
  )
# ---- NOTE: changes list object name
lm_list <- 
  setNames(lm_list, paste("lm_list", 
                          mtcars_DVs$Variable_name,
                          sep = "__")
  )
```

I then used `confint()` on the list to create a list of `confint` objects, and turned that into list of data frames, with specific DV based names for each data frame.

```
## creates coef object
lm_confint_list <- 
  lapply(
    lm_list, 
    function(model_list) {
      confint(model_list)
    }
  )
# ---- NOTE: changes list object name
lm_confint_list <- 
  setNames(lm_confint_list, paste("lm_confint_list", 
                          mtcars_DVs$Variable_name,
                          sep = "__")
  )
# ---- NOTE: creates unique objects for each part list object
list2env(lm_confint_list, .GlobalEnv)
# ---- NOTE: gathers objects with prefix
apropos("lm_confint_list")


## turns lm_confint_list into data frame
lm_confint_df_list <- 
  lapply(
    lm_confint_list, 
    function(model_list) {
      data.frame(model_list, header = TRUE)
    }
  )
# ---- NOTE: changes list object name
lm_confint_df_list <- 
  setNames(lm_confint_df_list, paste("lm_confint_df_list", 
                                  mtcars_DVs$Variable_name,
                                  sep = "__")
  )
# ---- NOTE: creates unique objects for each part list object
list2env(lm_confint_df_list, .GlobalEnv)
# ---- NOTE: gathers objects with prefix
apropos("lm_confint_df_list")
```

I now want (1) to add a variable to each list in the data frame that just has the name of the data frame list repeated, called `object_name`. I then want to (2) remove some of the text from this variable to create a variable with just the DV specific to that analysis, for each object in the list `Variable_name`.

I want to do (1) and (2) using iterated code without the need for manual input, expect for if I change the nature of the object `mtcars_DVs$Variable_name`  (i.e., add or remove possible dependent variables to be used to create the model lists).

Is this possible? I know how to do this the long way with a healthy amount of manual input, but not the short and iterated way with minimal manual input.

Thanks ahead of time.

---

---

Here is the long way to accomplish (1) and (2):

```
# long way of adding column with object name, will do one confint(), process can be repeated for other variables

## adds as column with name of object to object via manual text input
# ---- NOTE: REQUIRES MANUAL INPUT
lm_confint_df_list__disp$object_name <- "lm_confint_df_list__disp"

## creates column with DV from object_name variable
lm_confint_df_list__disp$Variable_name <- 
  gsub(".*__","",lm_confint_df_list__disp$object_name)
```

---

---

Here is the completed output of one of the lm confint results:

```
> lm_confint_df_list__disp
                X2.5..   X97.5.. header              object_name Variable_name
(Intercept) -228.45716 -84.76080   TRUE lm_confint_df_list__disp          disp
cyl           51.42909  73.76876   TRUE lm_confint_df_list__disp          disp
```

---

---

Here is all of the code I used.

```
# sets up data

## list of DVs to use
mtcars_DVs <- data.frame(c("mpg", "drat", "disp"))
names(mtcars_DVs)[names(mtcars_DVs) == "c..mpg....drat....disp.."] <- "Variable_name"
mtcars_DVs$Variable_name <- as.character(mtcars_DVs$Variable_name)

## creates lm object list
# ---- NOTE: creates object list
lm_list <-
  lapply(mtcars_DVs$Variable_name,
         function(DV_list) wrapr::let(
           c(DV_col = DV_list, 
             dataset_obj = "mtcars", 
             IV_col_key = "cyl"), 
           (lm(
             DV_col ~ 
               IV_col_key, 
             data = dataset_obj
           )
           )
         )
  )
# ---- NOTE: changes list object name
lm_list <- 
  setNames(lm_list, paste("lm_list", 
                          mtcars_DVs$Variable_name,
                          sep = "__")
  )

## creates coef object
lm_confint_list <- 
  lapply(
    lm_list, 
    function(model_list) {
      confint(model_list)
    }
  )
# ---- NOTE: changes list object name
lm_confint_list <- 
  setNames(lm_confint_list, paste("lm_confint_list", 
                          mtcars_DVs$Variable_name,
                          sep = "__")
  )
# ---- NOTE: creates unique objects for each part list object
list2env(lm_confint_list, .GlobalEnv)
# ---- NOTE: gathers objects with prefix
apropos("lm_confint_list")

## turns lm_confint_list into data frame
lm_confint_df_list <- 
  lapply(
    lm_confint_list, 
    function(model_list) {
      data.frame(model_list, header = TRUE)
    }
  )
# ---- NOTE: changes list object name
lm_confint_df_list <- 
  setNames(lm_confint_df_list, paste("lm_confint_df_list", 
                                  mtcars_DVs$Variable_name,
                                  sep = "__")
  )
# ---- NOTE: creates unique objects for each part list object
list2env(lm_confint_df_list, .GlobalEnv)
# ---- NOTE: gathers objects with prefix
apropos("lm_confint_df_list")




# long way of adding column with object name, will do one confint(), process can be repeated for other variables

## adds as column with name of object to object via manual text input
# ---- NOTE: REQUIRES MANUAL INPUT
lm_confint_df_list__disp$object_name <- "lm_confint_df_list__disp"

## creates column with DV from object_name variable
lm_confint_df_list__disp$Variable_name <- 
  gsub(".*__","",lm_confint_df_list__disp$object_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the help of `Map` :

```
lm_confint_df_list <- Map(function(x, y) 
            data.frame(x, object_name = y, Variable_name = gsub(".*__","",y), 
            check.names = FALSE), lm_confint_list, names(lm_confint_list))

lm_confint_df_list

#$lm_confint_list__mpg
#                2.5 %    97.5 %          object_name Variable_name
#(Intercept) 33.649223 42.119930 lm_confint_list__mpg           mpg
#cyl         -3.534237 -2.217343 lm_confint_list__mpg           mpg

#$lm_confint_list__drat
#                 2.5 %     97.5 %           object_name Variable_name
#(Intercept)  4.3803292  5.4059919 lm_confint_list__drat          drat
#cyl         -0.2892782 -0.1298242 lm_confint_list__drat          drat

#$lm_confint_list__disp
#                 2.5 %    97.5 %           object_name Variable_name
#(Intercept) -228.45716 -84.76080 lm_confint_list__disp          disp
#cyl           51.42909  73.76876 lm_confint_list__disp          disp
```

Put the individual objects in global variable.

```
list2env(lm_confint_df_list, .GlobalEnv)
```